# Randomly placed UILabel has wrong size after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, sizetofit, text-rotation

Have a UIVew container for multiple UILabels random generated, rotated and placed into this view, also if I am using angles 0, 90, 180, 270 looks good but if angle randomly generated labels looks expanded, and this is problem for me because words should be placed very close and without intersection, this how looks generator:

```
- (void) generate:(UIView *)container
            words:(NSArray *)words
           colors:(NSArray *)colors
      minFontSize:(float)minSize
      maxFontSize:(float)maxSize
      rotateWords:(BOOL)rotate
    useAngleRange:(BOOL)useRange
{
    usingRange = useRange;
    for (int i = 0; i < [words count]; i++) {
        UILabel *word_l = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        word_l.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"EuropeBold" size:[self getRandomNumberBetween:minSize to:(i < probableBigFontWords) ? maxSize : (maxSize / 3)]];
        [word_l setText:words[i]];
        [word_l setTextColor:colors[arc4random_uniform([colors count])]];
        [word_l setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [word_l sizeToFit];

        CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0,
                               0,
                               word_l.frame.size.width,
                               word_l.frame.size.height);
        word_l.frame = fr;
        word_l.center = CGPointMake([self getRandomNumberBetween:175 to:639], [self getRandomNumberBetween:175 to:375]);
        if (rotate) {
            int angleType = arc4random_uniform(2);
            if (useRange) {
                int angle = (angleType == 1) ? [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:90] : [self getRandomNumberBetween:270 to:360];
                [word_l setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle))];
            } else {
                [word_l setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((angleType == 1) ? DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270) : DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360))];
            }
        }
        [container addSubview:word_l];
        while ([self viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:container chosenView:word_l]) {
            viewPositionMovingStep++;
            [self placeItem:container :word_l];
        }
    }
}

- (void)placeItem:(UIView *)container :(UILabel *)word_l
{
    CGRect initFr = word_l.frame;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        CGRect f = word_l.frame;
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x + viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 2:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x + viewPositionMovingStep;
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y + viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 3:
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y + viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 4:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x - viewPositionMovingStep;
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y + viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 5:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x - viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 6:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x - viewPositionMovingStep;
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y - viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 7:
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y - viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            case 8:
                f.origin.x = f.origin.x + viewPositionMovingStep;
                f.origin.y = f.origin.y - viewPositionMovingStep;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        word_l.frame = f;
        if ([self viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:container chosenView:word_l]) {
            word_l.frame = initFr;
        } else {
            viewPositionMovingStep = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
}

-(BOOL)viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:(UIView *)container chosenView:(UIView *)chosenView
{
    for(UIView *view in [container subviews]){
        if (![chosenView isEqual:view]){
            BOOL framePartiallyOut = !CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(chosenView.superview.bounds, chosenView.frame), chosenView.frame);
            if (usingRange) {
                if([self view:chosenView intersectsWith:view] || framePartiallyOut){
                    return YES;
                }
            } else {
                if(CGRectIntersectsRect(chosenView.frame, view.frame) || framePartiallyOut){
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)view:(UIView *)view1 intersectsWith:(UIView *)view2
{
    CGPoint poly1[4];
    CGRect bounds1 = view1.bounds;
    poly1[0] = [view1 convertPoint:bounds1.origin toView:nil];
    poly1[1] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x + bounds1.size.width, bounds1.origin.y) toView:nil];
    poly1[2] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x + bounds1.size.width, bounds1.origin.y + bounds1.size.height) toView:nil];
    poly1[3] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x, bounds1.origin.y + bounds1.size.height) toView:nil];

    CGPoint poly2[4];
    CGRect bounds2 = view2.bounds;
    poly2[0] = [view2 convertPoint:bounds2.origin toView:nil];
    poly2[1] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x + bounds2.size.width, bounds2.origin.y) toView:nil];
    poly2[2] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x + bounds2.size.width, bounds2.origin.y + bounds2.size.height) toView:nil];
    poly2[3] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x, bounds2.origin.y + bounds2.size.height) toView:nil];

    CGPoint ctl2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[0] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, ctl2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctr2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[1] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, ctr2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbr2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[2] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, cbr2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbl2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[3] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, cbl2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctl1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[0] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, ctl1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctr1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[1] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, ctr1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbr1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[2] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, cbr1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbl1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[3] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, cbl1)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to
{
    return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

this how looks right placed labels:

[image: well transformed subviews]

and this example short word with random generated angles (range 270-360, 0-90):

[image]

as you have noticed, no text showing there, labels looks expanded and intersection checker is not working in this case, also if function called from `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidApper` this checkers is not working at all, I really need help, any ideas guys? 
Thank you!

Comment: i think, random values are clashing when you are checking for intersection. but still not able to figure out why no label displayed.

Comment: @Mahesh Agrawala but how about label's width? they looks too long even if contains 3-4 symbols

Comment: can you set the tag for every label and to reset the rotation position which using to "label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;" and reset the frame  label

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P my answer below, but anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

resizing problem was fixed this way:

```
- (void)placeItem:(UIView *)container :(UILabel *)word_l
{
    CGPoint initPoint = word_l.center;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x + viewPositionMovingStep, word_l.center.y);
                break;
            case 2:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x + viewPositionMovingStep, word_l.center.y + viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            case 3:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x, word_l.center.y + viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            case 4:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x - viewPositionMovingStep, word_l.center.y + viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            case 5:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x - viewPositionMovingStep, word_l.center.y);
                break;
            case 6:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x - viewPositionMovingStep,  - viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            case 7:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x, word_l.center.y - viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            case 8:
                word_l.center = CGPointMake(word_l.center.x + viewPositionMovingStep, word_l.center.y - viewPositionMovingStep);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if ([self viewIntersectsWithAnotherView:container chosenView:word_l]) {
            word_l.center = initPoint;
        } else {
            viewPositionMovingStep = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

the reason is:
When using the transform property you are not allowed to change the position by changing the frame, you have to use the center property.

So this part was fixed but left issue related with rotated view intersection, checker is not working properly, but testing it separately in other project it doing well.

There he is:

```
- (BOOL)view:(UIView *)view1 intersectsWith:(UIView *)view2
{
    CGPoint poly1[4];
    CGRect bounds1 = view1.bounds;
    poly1[0] = [view1 convertPoint:bounds1.origin toView:nil];
    poly1[1] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x + bounds1.size.width, bounds1.origin.y) toView:nil];
    poly1[2] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x + bounds1.size.width, bounds1.origin.y + bounds1.size.height) toView:nil];
    poly1[3] = [view1 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds1.origin.x, bounds1.origin.y + bounds1.size.height) toView:nil];

    CGPoint poly2[4];
    CGRect bounds2 = view2.bounds;
    poly2[0] = [view2 convertPoint:bounds2.origin toView:nil];
    poly2[1] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x + bounds2.size.width, bounds2.origin.y) toView:nil];
    poly2[2] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x + bounds2.size.width, bounds2.origin.y + bounds2.size.height) toView:nil];
    poly2[3] = [view2 convertPoint:CGPointMake(bounds2.origin.x, bounds2.origin.y + bounds2.size.height) toView:nil];

    CGPoint ctl2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[0] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, ctl2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctr2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[1] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, ctr2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbr2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[2] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, cbr2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbl2 = [view1 convertPoint:poly2[3] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view1.bounds, cbl2)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctl1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[0] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, ctl1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint ctr1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[1] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, ctr1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbr1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[2] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, cbr1)){
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint cbl1 = [view2 convertPoint:poly1[3] fromView:nil];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view2.bounds, cbl1)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

someone ideas?